# Can check box and link be together? If not then what is the best UX to have on screen: icon or view more link?

Tags: users, tree

In my screen,left side text is clickable. You can click on parent level and see their child after parent. Parent and child has text box to delete or bulk delete. I want to give capability to user that user can click on right side and see parent and child level and drill in the child level. 
Can i give check box and text link together ?
If no then what will be best ux to understand that user can go in child level by clicking right side?
Can i give icon near delete button ?
Can give view detail link after text ?

[image]

Comment: I am unsure why you need two separate panels. You could fit all the information in the same panel. Also, I'm not sure I understood the purpose of the checkbox?

Answer (score 1):

In your query, the text link is meant to be checkbox label. If the checkbox has a correct association with its label, the label could be clickable. No need to make it a link.

To answer your UX concern, Is it possible to do everything in the left panel, is there any reason for the right side panel? You can have the delete button in the left tree view itself.

If you need to display, the attributes, details, and contents related to the selected node, then the right panel will do that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need two panels. An icon such as an arrow is a common way to indicate children in a tree view. Down pointing arrow means there are children, side arrow means the group is open, no arrow means no children. Then your actions can still be on the side

```
> Group 1                     [delete bulk]
      Group 11                     [delete]
    > Group 12                [delete bulk]
          Group 121                [delete]
v Group 2                          [delete]
v Group 3                          [delete]
  Group 4                          [delete]
```